# Binding TimeSpan larger than 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi Controller like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutSomeValue(TimeSpan ts){ ... }
```

If I PUT this, it binds as 23 hours:

```
{
  "ts": "23:00:00"
}
```

But if I PUT this, it binds as 24 days:

```
{
  "ts": "24:00:00"
}
```

And if I PUT this, it fails with a 400:

```
{
  "ts": "24:30:00"
}
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [TimeSpan.Parse docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)- they show the full format spec. Looks like `12.12:12:12` should give you 12d 12h 12m 12s.

Comment: Ah, so it should be 1.00:00:00